# How to Save Manged Metadata value in List using JSOM or REST...?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, jsom, office365apis

As i have understand it by googling a litle, that its not posible to use REST for Taxonomy fields ? I was not able to update my list doing it by http REST .
But it should be posible with JSOM.

How can I save a managed metadata value in my `SP.List`?
I have a list with one MMD column which I want to update.

My code looks like:

```
  $scope.saveProsessConnection = function (propertyName) {
        var taxPickerIndex = $("#taxPickerOpenSingle").val();
        console.log(taxPickerIndex);
        var result = $.parseJSON(taxPickerIndex);
        console.log(result);
        var listTitle = "GNTiles";
        var taxFieldName = "Prosess";
        var termGUID = result[0].Id;
        var termLabel = result[0].Name;
        console.log(termGUID);
        console.log(result);

        var context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var item = list.getItemById(tileId);
        //console.log('Item Id: '+item.id);

        var termValue = "-1" + ";#" + termLabel + "|" + termGUID;
        item.set_item(taxFieldName, termValue);
        item.update();


        context.load(item);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);


        function onSuccess() {
            //retriveListItem(); 
            console.log("Success!!")
        }

        function onFailure(sender, args) {
            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }
```

And my data looks like :

```
[{"Id":"e0a1f57a-6746-4ecc-b119-47f2ff80a1ea","Name":"L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","PathOfTerm":"L3 Lede og forbedre;L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","Children":[],"Level":1,"RawTerm":null}]
```

The error iam getting is:

> Request failed. Unexpected response data from server.
>   null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i resolved my case with updating a List Item with Managed Metadata Column.

```
        function execRequest() {
        var taxPickerIndex = $("#taxPickerOpenSingle").val();
        var result = $.parseJSON(taxPickerIndex);
        var listTitle = "GNTiles";
        var taxFieldName = "Process";
        var termId = result[0].Id;
        var term = result[0].Name;
        console.log("Term ID: " + termId);
        console.log(result);

        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var item = list.getItemById(tileId);

        var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Prosess");
        var txField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);

        context.load(field);
        context.load(txField);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            //Get the term set ID  
           // var termSetId = txField.get_termSetId().toString();
            var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
            var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);

            // Get the matching terms based on names  
            var lmi = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(context);
            lmi.set_lcid(1033);
            lmi.set_trimUnavailable(true);
            lmi.set_termLabel("UI Developer");

            var termMatches = termSet.getTerms(lmi);
            context.load(termMatches);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
                var termFieldValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();
                termFieldValue.set_label(term);
                termFieldValue.set_termGuid(termId);
                termFieldValue.set_wssId(-1);
                txField.setFieldValueByValue(item, termFieldValue);
                item.update();

                context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    console.log('Item Added');
                }, function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                });
             }, function (sender, args) {  
                console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
             });

        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet can be used to update MMD field

```
var termValue = "-1;#" + termLabel + "|" + termGUID;
item.set_item("Process", termValue);
item.update();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i did almost like you showed in your comment "Amal". But still iam getting error:

Comment: Can you confirm the Id and Value is proper?

Comment: yes Id and value is proper....

Comment: Here is how my data looks like:  [{"Id":"e0a1f57a-6746-4ecc-b119-47f2ff80a1ea","Name":"L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","PathOfTerm":"L3 Lede og forbedre;L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","Children":[],"Level":1,"RawTerm":null}]

Comment: You can se how data looks like in comment above, i just get an error on context.executeQueryAsync : Request failed. Unexpected response data from server.
null

Comment: Now i have tested my code by adding a simple plain text field in my list, and try to update it by setting some dummy string in my code to se if updating item works. But still iam getting same error:  Request failed. Unexpected response data from server.
null

Comment: Check if its a cross domain issue.. http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2015/03/getting-unexpected-response-data-from-server-error-using-sharepoint-jsom/